# Cómo se dice en Español "Vesting"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

"[Vesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesting)", en el sentido finaciero o legal, es un activo que se te otorga pero del que no puedes ejercer pleno derecho hasta pasado un cierto tiempo o se den unas condiciones.

Por ejemplo, cuando comienzas a trabajar para la empresa X, esta te da 100 acciones de la empresa (una forma adicional de remunerarte y una motivación adicional para que te quedes en la empresa y trabajes para que la empresa, y su cotización en bolsa, mejoren). Pero, desde luego, no puedes vender esas acciones el segundo día de empezar a trabajar para X. Aunque nadie te puede quitar esas acciones, no puedes hacer nada con ellas hasta pasado un año, tras el cual te dan el 25% de esas acciones (y así otro 25% cada año, hasta que al cabo de 4 años ya te han otrorgado el 100% de esas acciones que te daban al principio).

Tras el primer año, puedes hacer lo que quieras con esas 25 acciones (bueno, seguramente no del todo, para evitar *insider trading* y otras situaciones similares).

Aunque se pueden encontrar [ciertas sugerencias](http://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/vesting.html) para traducir el término en la red, no estoy seguro de que apliquen al caso que he descrito, y esperaba poder encontrar algo de ayuda por aquí.

¿Cómo puede traducirse `vesting` (o `vested`) al español?

Comment: El IATE coincide con tu enlace y las denomina "derechos adquiridos" y "derechos consolidados" conforme van consolidándose con el paso del tiempo.

Comment: Versting serían los "adquiridos" entonces, y "vested" los consolidados, verdad?

Comment: Pues así lo entiendo yo, sí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El *[Black's Law Dictionary](http://thelawdictionary.org/)*, que es una fuente casi irrefutable en lo que a terminología legal anglosajona se refiere, habla más de "vested interest" como un derecho adquirido de ejercicio futuro. Según este diccionario, el "vested right" tiene más contundencia y actualidad que el "vested interest" y se usa más en derecho constitucional, como derechos propios de las personas. (En cambio, según la definición de wikipedia el "vested interest" es un "vested right" transmisible a terceros.)

> **VESTED INTEREST.** *A present right or title to a thing, which carries with it an existing right of alienation, **even though the right to possession or enjoyment may be postponed to some uncertain time in the future**, as distinguished from a future right, which may never materialize or ripen into title, and it matters not how long or for what length of time the future possession or right of enjoyment may be postponed, if the present right exists to alientate and pass title.* (negritas con bastardillas mías)
>
> **VESTED RIGHTS.** *Rights which have **so completely and definitely accrued to or settled in a person** that they are not subject to be defeated or canceled by the act of any other person, and which it is right and equitable that the government should recognize and protect, as being lawful in themselves, and settled according to the then current rules of law, and of which the individual could not be deprived arbitrarily without injustice, or of which he could not justly be deprived otherwise than by the established methods of procedure and for the public welfare.* (negritas con bastardillas mías)

En cuanto a la traducción de "vesting", creo que necesariamente debe utilizarse un sustantivo indicativo de acción, como "otorgamiento" (otros podrían ser "concesión", "asignación" o "adjudicación"). Como ocurre con muchos términos propios de otras culturas o, en este caso, legislaciones, a menudo debemos recurrir a frases para su correcta traducción. Si el ejercicio de los derechos en el futuro es seguro, como parece ser el caso de las acciones entregadas a los funcionarios como parte de su remuneración, podríamos hablar de "**otorgamiento de derechos de ejercicio futuro**" (Fuente: [Sitio de traductores](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/english_to_spanish/law_contracts/775757-oraci%C3%B3n_phrase.html)). De lo contrario, podríamos hablar de "otorgamiento de derechos contingentes/de ejercicio eventual".